# Does Azure Data Lake support content search?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I have tried going through the Azure data lake documentation in MSDN as well as couple of slides in slideshare to figure out an answer. From what I gathered, The Azure Data Catalog is used for discoverability based on metadata and few annotations user can provide. Would not having a content based search add more value to the lake?

Answer (score 1):

Content search and full-text search on data in the Data Lake can be very useful indeed.

I would expect that you could use either HDINSIGHT or U-SQL's extensibility mechanism, to add content search (and indexing) with something like Lucene or Solr.

If you would like to see something out of the box, please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback. Thanks!